# How can I view queued Scheduled Reminders?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Is there a way to view Scheduled Reminders that are scheduled to go out the next time the job runs?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Scheduled Reminders are not actually queued, they are selected when the Scheduled Reminders cron job runs. But if they are queued you should be able to see them in the *civicrm_queue_item* table.

Comment: is there a way to view which reminders will be selected with the next cron run?

Comment: No without checking the code and the database I would guess :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with Scheduled Reminders on Events recently and so looked at this to understand it more, so sharing what I found.

The cron job that fires off Reminders is called **Send Scheduled Reminders**.  My issue was it was set to run just daily and thus any intraday reminder would not be sent on time.

Scheduled reminders are stored in the **civicrm_action_schedule** table.  You can see the ID of the Entity e.g. Event, Contact field etc in the entity_value column.  The 'mapping_id' column tells you what type of Entity it relates to. Mappings are stored in the **civicrm_action_mapping** table.  To complete the picture, the **civicrm_action_log** table shows you what actions have taken place and with whom.

You can see this system in action most clearly for Events. Create a test Event and then set a reminder e.g. one day before the start of the event, go to your SQL tool of choice and look at the entry in the civicrm_action_schedule table.  You'll see the ID of the Event itself is shown in that entity_value column, along with the type of recipient (e.g. participant_role) in the recipent column. The rest of the columns are pretty much self explanatory and you'll see the mapping_id relates to the Event entity type if you look.

If you manually create a Scheduled Reminder through Administer > Communications > Schedule Reminders for something more obscure e.g. an email going out to a Contact entity on the anniversay of some event marked by a custom field, you'll see the entity_id as the custom field id stored in the  **civicrm_custom_field** table.

So, you do need to understand the underlying details of the Entity that the reminder is for, but at least you can see them there!